# sencha touch / phonegap :: looking for code-scrambler

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, scramble

Does anybody have a good tip for a javascript code scrambler which runs good on sencha touch and phonegap?

thnx!

Comment: What do you mean by code scrambler? Do you want to obfuscate the code so it's not human readable?

Comment: yes and loaded faster (all in one strin/line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case I would suggest something like Google closure compiler.

http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

You can try it online to see what it will do to your code here:

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: thank you. and in other cases?

Comment: Another popular choice is Yahoo's YUI Compressor: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/